# What are the exact effects of braces in this for-loop?

Tags: c#

I have a question about the for loop: This code should add 6 random numbers to  3 different boxes. This code instead puts 21 numbers to each box (*1). I could solve this problem by either removing the braces from the second for-loop(*2) or writing  a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); in front of the braces(*3). But why?

**1**

```
        int[,] a;
        a = new int[7, 3];

        listeBox.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)    //false
        {

            for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++) 

            {
                a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); 
                listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]);
                listBox1.Items.Add(a[i, 1]);
                listBox2.Items.Add(a[i, 2]);
            }   

        }
```

**2**

```
                for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++) //correct


                a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); 
                listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]);
                listBox1.Items.Add(a[i, 1]);
                listBox2.Items.Add(a[i, 2]);
```

**3**

```
             for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++) //correct

              a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); 

            {
                listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]);
                listBox1.Items.Add(a[i, 1]);
                listBox2.Items.Add(a[i, 2]);
            }
```

Comment: `{` and `}` are braces. Brackets are `[` and `]`.

Comment: Oh thx will correct it.

Comment: I'm only pointing that out since it may make your Googling more productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works because, other than the line `a[i,k] = r.Next(20,31)`, none of the other lines inside of your block use `k` for anything. In the first example,

```
for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++) 
{     
    a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); 
    listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]);
    listBox1.Items.Add(a[i, 1]);
    listBox2.Items.Add(a[i, 2]);    
}
```

The `listBox...` lines do exactly the same thing each time through the `k` loop, so you're unnecessarily doing the same thing over and over.

In your second example, the lack of braces means that the loop only executes the line

```
a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31);
```

This is the same as saying

```
for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++) //correct
    a[i, k] = r.Next(20, 31); 

listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]);
listBox1.Items.Add(a[i, 1]);
listBox2.Items.Add(a[i, 2]);
```

Once the `k` loop is complete, it moves on to the `listBox.Items.Add(...)` code.

In the third example, the braces are not attached to the loop, so you're creating a block without any control structure. It's functionally identical to your second example. It can be useful to create blocks in that way in many circumstances but, in your case, it does nothing.

Comment: After reading your answer and thinking about it, I would like to know, if this is correct what I assume: In the frist example k is seen as a local variable, so because of the loop it will go through the states of 0 to 2 and each listbox will gain 3 random numbers. In the second example listeBox.Items.Add(a[i, 0]); is not included in the for loop body anymore which means the 0 will not be seen as a replacement of k and with that each box gets one random value. Is that correct? I hope it was not too confusing.